# Forcing a JMP rel32 (JMPQ)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, instruction-encoding

If I do something like (dummy example):

```
jmp 1f
1: ret
```

on gcc/clang it generates a short relative jump because the label is near.

I'm curious, is it possible to force a `JMP rel32` regardless of the label's distance?

[Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch)'s suggestion in the comments to hardcode `jmpq` via its bytecode `0xe9` unfortunately only works with local labels, but I would like something that works with global linker-resolved labels too.

Since my real goal is to paste a constant-length jump instruction via a macro, I can also make do with stuff like `jmp 1: /*definitely short*/; 1: jmp /*short or long*/ actual_target_with_unclear_distance;`, relying on the first jump being definitely short, but using just one definitely-long jump would be shorter and cleaner if there's any way to achieve it.

Comment: You could simulate it a hackish way by building the jmp rel32 manually (you could improve it by putting it in a macro):  `.byte 0xe9` `.long (1f - 4) - .`
`1: ret`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Love the brute force of that. Thank you!

Comment: For reference, NASM allows `jmp strict near ...`

Comment: [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#InstructionModifiers) allows suffix S|N|F to mnemonic name `JMPN lf` or explicit distance modifier Short|Near|Far `JMP lf, dist=near`.

Comment: Michael Petch's suggestion of `.long (target - 4) - .` works for symbols defined in other object files.  Or equivalently, `.long (target - 1f)` ; `1:` to calculate relative to a label placed at the anchor point where the `jmp` is relative to.   That gets a `R_X86_64_PC32        target-0x4` relocation similar to `jmp target` which gets a `R_X86_64_PLT32`.  Those are equivalent as long as one of the `.o` files you link against defines the symbol so it can resolve at static link time, not runtime text-relocation. (e.g. `.global target` ; `target:` or a non-static C function.)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as.pdf), section 9.16.8 "Jump instructions are always optimized to use the smallest possible displacements". This seems to imply there is no manual way to override it. There is an addr32 instruction prefix in 9.16.6 but it is only allowed in `.code16`. I cannot seem to find an option that would control the size of `jmp` offset in any "official" source.

However, according to [this source](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/binutils/2008-March/055602.html) marking the label you jump to as global will make the `jmp` instruction use a `rel32` offset. I only managed to reproduce the behavior using clang though, GCC does not seem to work. Additionally, i cannot seem to find any more credible source for this behavior than the mentioned 15-year-old archived mailing list reply so i would not exactly call it "reliable". I assume it might go away unnoticed with some future update to clang/llvm-as.

For an example, following file `test_asm.s`:

```
.global main
main:
jmp lab
.global lab
lab: ret
```

compiled with `clang test_asm.s` on my machine results in:

```
000000000000111c <main>:
    111c:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmp    1121 <lab>

0000000000001121 <lab>:
    1121:   c3                      ret
```

Meanwhile, after removing the `.global lab` line the result is:

```
000000000000111c <main>:
    111c:   eb 00                   jmp    111e <lab>

000000000000111e <lab>:
    111e:   c3                      ret
```

For a reliable, although a tedious solution, you can always manually encode the `jmp` instruction to bytes and then input them using the `.byte` directive in place of the `jmp <operand>` mnemonic, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up with Michael Petch's solution: `#define MY_asm_jmpq(Target) .byte 0xe9; .long ((Target) - 4) - .` (I use C macros. I put macro-stringified asm in my C sources and use C macros inside of the the asm where appropriate). I find reliable less tedious than navigating around assembler quirks.

Comment: I had to do this with VASM for 68000 Assembly. My interrupt code was crashing because the assembler was optimizing `JSR` into `BSR` (an absolute call vs. a relative call) and it was messing up my interrupt handlers (which were being copied to RAM to avoid the overhead of switch cases)

Comment: `addr32` is *not* what you want to affect how the displacement is encoded.  It would override the address-size with a `0x67` prefix byte, making it not truncate EIP to IP.  Or in 64-bit mode, making it truncate RIP to EIP.